# Subtract two Price input types and display result

Tags: product-attribute

I'd like to show visitors to my website an instant savings based on subtracting 2 attributes **costnopromo** and **cost**.

If the attributes are the same, then I do not want to display the text, "Save:"

I know I can do this with an if statement, but I do not know how to subtract the 2 attributes.

How do can achieve the following:

**costnopromo** - **cost** = savings_value

NOTE: I've searched and came across the method to show a savings based on MSRP and PRICE but this does not meet my requirements as the **costnopromo** is a custom value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product collection output get from,

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

to get the costnopromo and cost values by,

```
echo $_product->getCostnopromo();
echo $_product->getCost();
```

To substract,

```
$savings_value = intval($_product->getCostnopromo()) - intval($_product->getCost());
```

by checking the condition,

```
 if($savings_value >= 0){
    echo 'save :'.$savings_value;
 }
```

this may help you

Comment: Gave you the accepted as its more complete. Thanks! SR

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $_product is a valid product object...

```
$savingValue = $_product->getCostnopromo() - $_product->getCost();

if ($savingValue >= 0) {
    echo "Save: " . $savingValue;
}
```

Comment: Gave you +1 for correct answer, but was not as complete a Helphin. Thanks! SR